# What is $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I often read that: $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]=[0,1)$. But why?

My intuition would say that the result would be $[0,1]$ because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]=[0,1]$

Comment: Which one of the sets $[0,1-\frac1n]$ do you think contains the element $1$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was asked several hundred times before.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941753/an-argument-with-my-friend-over-bigcup-a-frac1n-b would be of some help

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hence the downvote or what?

Comment: @MattN.: I didn't vote on this question. It's +3 anyway. And your answer is +5, and I didn't vote on it either. Neither of which has any downvotes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok. (Edit: True, the two downvoters seem to have changed their minds...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila One can never be suspicious enough though : )  I apologize, my bad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask yourself: Which of the sets $[0, 1 - {1\over n}]$ contains $1$?

The answer is: None. Hence the union $\bigcup_n [0,1-{1\over n}]$ cannot contain $1$ since none of the sets $[0, 1 - {1\over n}]$ does.

Comment: Can you make up your mind whether you want to down vote or up vote?

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in\cup[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ then $x\in[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But $[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]\subseteq[0,1)$ so we have the first inclusion. 
If $x\in [0,1)$ then $x<1-\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so 
$x\in\cup[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ and we obtain the second inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

If something belongs to the union of sets it has to belong to at least one of the sets. Lets assume that $1 \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\Big]$ so it means that there exist an index $n_0$ that $1 \in \Big[0,1-\frac{1}{n_0}\Big]$ but it means that $0 < 1 < 1 - \frac{1}{n_0}$ which leads to contradiction.